# merging with changing the form of columns

Tags: r

I have two data frames named "df" and "df1". what i want is merging df with df1 based on gender and district in such a way that after merging I only have one column of "prob.dis". more clearly, I want that if dis is 1, then the value from prob.dis1` should be used, and if dis is 5, then I want the value from prob.dis5.any help would be appreciated.

```
df<-
     age gender   dis
     10      1     1
     11      2     5
     10      1     4
     11      2     2
     10      1     1
     11      2     2
     10      1     4
     11      2     5
     10      1     3
     11      2     3

df1<-
    age gender prob.dis1 prob.dis2 prob.dis3 prob.dis4 prob.dis5
    10      1    0.0099    0.0124    0.0037    0.0176       0.1
    11      2    0.0021    0.802     0.005     0.0029       0.2
```

Comment: You'd get faster respnses if you post **reproducible data**

Answer (score 1):

Transform `df1` into long format and join it with `df` on `gender` and `dis`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches("^prob.dis"),
    names_to = c(".value", "dis"),
    names_pattern = "([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)"
  ) %>%
  mutate(dis = as.integer(dis)) %>%
  select(-age) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = c("gender", "dis"))

     age gender   dis prob.dis
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1    10      1     1   0.0099
 2    11      2     5   0.2   
 3    10      1     4   0.0176
 4    11      2     2   0.802 
 5    10      1     1   0.0099
 6    11      2     2   0.802 
 7    10      1     4   0.0176
 8    11      2     5   0.2   
 9    10      1     3   0.0037
10    11      2     3   0.005
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(age = c(10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11
), gender = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), dis = c(1, 5, 4, 
2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df1 <- structure(list(age = c(10, 11), gender = c(1, 2), prob.dis1 = c(0.0099, 
0.0021), prob.dis2 = c(0.0124, 0.802), prob.dis3 = c(0.0037, 
0.005), prob.dis4 = c(0.0176, 0.0029), prob.dis5 = c(0.1, 0.2
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

Comment: Can you post the data you used?

Comment: you mean dput data?

Comment: The curly braces are not really necessary, are they?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

1. `pivot_longer` `df2`
2. `right_join` with `df1`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("prob"),
         names_to = "dis",
         values_to = "prob.dis"
    ) %>% 
  mutate(dis = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", dis))) %>% 
  right_join(df1, by = c("age", "gender", "dis"))
```

Output:

```
    age gender   dis prob.dis
   <int>  <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1    10      1     1   0.0099
 2    10      1     1   0.0099
 3    10      1     3   0.0037
 4    10      1     4   0.0176
 5    10      1     4   0.0176
 6    11      2     2   0.802 
 7    11      2     2   0.802 
 8    11      2     3   0.005 
 9    11      2     5   0.2   
10    11      2     5   0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

In case *dis* is only ranging from 1 to 5 and is sorted in the columns of `df2` you can use `match` to find the row and use `2 + df$dis` to get the column, which can be subseted with a matrix produced with `cbind`.

```
df$prop.dis <- df1[cbind(match(df$gender, df1$gender), 2 + df$dis)]
df
#   age gender dis prop.dis
#1   10      1   1   0.0099
#2   11      2   5   0.2000
#3   10      1   4   0.0176
#4   11      2   2   0.8020
#5   10      1   1   0.0099
#6   11      2   2   0.8020
#7   10      1   4   0.0176
#8   11      2   5   0.2000
#9   10      1   3   0.0037
#10  11      2   3   0.0050
```

or using the `names` of `df1` to `match` the colums:

```
df$prop.dis <- df1[cbind(match(df$gender, df1$gender)
                       , match(paste0("prob.dis", df$dis), names(df1)))]
```

In case also *age* should be matched use in addition `interaction`:

```
M <- c("age", "gender")
df$prop.dis <- df1[cbind(match(interaction(df[M]), interaction(df1[M])), 2 + df$dis)]
```

Comment: thank you. but it should also match with age in df and df1. how can i add age match in your suggested code?

Comment: Use in addition `interaction` -> see updated answer.